# XORing string in C programming linux drivers

Tags: c, linux-kernel, pipe, linux-device-driver

I am doing a very simple character driver.
I have write function:

```
/**********************************************************************
 **  Called when the device is written to
 **********************************************************************/
static ssize_t device_write( struct file *filep, const char *buf,
    size_t len, loff_t *f_pos ) {
  int i=0,j=0;
  int bytesToWrite;
  char text[BUFSZ];
  char key[256];
  int keySize;
  // generate key and determine it's size
  while( buf[i] != ' '){
    key[i] = buf[i];
    i++;
  }
  i++;
  while ( buf[i] !='\0'){
    text[j] = buf[i];
    j++;i++;
  }
  keySize = strlen(key);
  len = len-keySize-1;
  if (len < BUFSZ ) bytesToWrite = len;
  else if (len >= BUFSZ) {
    bytesToWrite = BUFSZ;
  }
  ksa(state,key,keySize);
  prga(state,stream,len);

  for (j=0;j<len;j++){
    temp_buffer[j] = stream[j]^text[j];
  }
  down(&isPipeWritten); // if isPipeWritten!=0 ? isPipeWritten-- : wait
  down(&pipe);
  // clear the buffer
  memset( internal_buffer, 0, BUFSZ );
  *f_pos = 0;
  // copy the data from the user into the internal buffer
  if ( copy_from_user( &internal_buffer,buf, bytesToWrite ) != 0 )
    return -EFAULT;
  up(&isPipeRead); // isPipeRead=1; full
  up(&pipe);
  return bytesToWrite;
}
```

So, when writer writes to the device driver it:

1. takes a key, which is first string
2. takes the rest of text
3. pass key to ksa and prga to generate a cipher.

   prga returns stream[len]
4. xor text with stream[len]
5. should cop cipher to internall_buffer

Here are the problems:

1. can't xor, ubuntu stops.
2. and also can not pass string other that buf itself to copy_from_user

I spend a whole day trying to figure it out, but I am a newbie.
Also if you see some variable that is not declared, it means it is global. I just didn't copied that code.

Comment: Please format your code properly, according to [Linux kernel coding style](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle), and split code blocks by empty lines.

Comment: amongst other things,  1) the normal way to declare a file pointer is 'FILE*' not 'struct file *'.   when copying leading spaces, to key[i], then increment 'i', copying the rest of the input to text[j],  a character is skipped in buf[i] due to the 'i++' between the two while loops.  Note: the key[] is neither pre-initialized to all '\0' nor is the string terminated, so 'strlen(key)' could be anything.  When copying to text[], need to check that text[] buffer not overrun.  Need to terminate string in text[] or pre set text[] to all '\0'

Comment: the writer of that 'Linux kernel coding style' has the mis-perception that tabs are always 8 spaces.   That is patiently wrong.  Any decent word processor can set the tab stops anywhere.  Any decent editor can set the tab width to anything.  Therefore, using tabs for indentation is a very bad idea because each editor/word processor can/will display the code differently.   I.E, use spaces.   *I* prefer 4 spaces as that is wide enough to be visible even when using a variable width font.

Comment: continuing, brace placement, per the writer should be like K&R did it (opening brace at end of line.  *I* knew Richie.  He told me they did it that way due to a limitation in original C compiler.  That is now known as 'georgian' formatting.  It has a major drawback.  The drawback is the human eye must travel left/right over a considerable distance to find the opening/closing braces.  For human beings, a straight vertical scan is much easier and more reliable.   There are a other bad ideas expressed in the document, which make maintenance much more difficult

Comment: continuing,  I do agree with the objective of the writer,  Namely, code should be written, not for the sake of the compiler, but rather for the sake of the human reader and always remembering that code is written once, but maintained forever, usually by a different person than the one that originally wrote it.

Comment: @user3629249, This is kernel code, so `struct file *` is the proper argument. Your rant about coding style is off-base. If you should ever be tempted to contribute code to the linux kernel, your patches will be rejected if they do not follow the prescribed style.

Comment: OTOH, the lack of null-terminator on `key` is well-spotted. That may be the proximate cause of the OP's problem.

Comment: @user3629249 All the kernel code is written with specific coding style in mind (doesn't matter how good it is, btw I'd say you are wrong about all things you have written). Anyway, if OP wants people to look into his problem, he should: **1.** Format his code as it's required by project's coding style (because it's easier for kernel developer to read)  **2.** Provide [minimal compilable](http://sscce.org/) example which reproduces his issue. If he doesn't want to waste his time on it -- why should I waste my time doing that for him?

Answer (score 1):

You have some of this backwards. First, you should use `copy_from_user` to pull the data from the user buffer into your own local buffer *before* processing it. You should *never* directly dereference user pointers (what if, for example, the user hands you a kernel address that contains some other user's private data). The buffer argument is usually declared something like this: `const char __user *user_buf` to insure you don't improperly use it.

Second, you must make sure not to overflow your buffer, so you should range-check before calling `copy_from_user` to make sure that the user data will fit in your internal buffer for example, what if the user passes you a length of 4gig (possibly you can also dynamically allocate the internal buffer if you don't want to impose an artificial limitation).

Likewise, when copying text (`while( buf[i] != ' '){` you must add a length check to ensure you don't run off the end of either source or destination.

Having done all that, it's not possible for the xor operation itself to cause a kernel panic or oops. That is, a kernel panic (kernel stopping, whatever) almost certainly means that you are accessing memory you should not be accessing, resulting in a kernel page fault. Page faults in kernel code are only allowed in certain well-defined circumstances -- for example, when fulfilling a `copy_from_user` -- and even then only on user addresses. Kernel data addresses should never cause page faults.